# Subdivision surface modifier, faces not connecting

Tags: faces, subdivision-surface

I have added some holes in my model using *Boolean` modifier (it is applied) and I have some problems with the *Sub Surface* modifier., it seems like the faces are not connecting.

I have made sure there are no overlapping vertices and every face has 4 vertices.
(I am still pretty new to Blender)

Before the *Sub Surface* modifier.
[image: mesh before sub surface modifier]

This is after.
[image: after sub surface modifier]

It makes these rounded edges on the faces in the corners.

[image: close up]

[image]

Comment: maybe some vertices are overlapping/not connected, try to select all and Alt M to Merge by Distance?

Comment: I have already tried/done that, but thank you.

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=NXN2sOGq" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/NXN2sOGq/)

Comment: hope this is right.

Comment: you are using the Edge Split modifier, it disjoins the faces, I don't know why Sharp Edges doesn't correct it, I don't know enough about this method, maybe someone will answer. You have other methods to sharp angles by the way, like Bevel modifier (or simply give it additional edges)

Answer (score 1):

As moonboots suggested, the Edge Split modifier is the culprit here. It literally turns every edge into 2 edges creating disconnected faces which messes with subsurf.
[Edge Split Modifier Doco](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/edge_split.html)
You can test this by turning "Sharp Edges" off and reducing the "Edge Angle" value down to 0. You will notice that every face becomes rounded as though every face is disconnected. (Cool effect though!)
[image: Edge Angle at 0]

For what you are trying to achieve, using Crease is a much better option.
Delete the Edge Split modifier, select the edges you wish the subsurf modifier not to effect and hit Shift-E to add a crease to those edges. It is a bit of an art knowing which edges to apply Crease to but you will learn it as you go. The crease value can also be found in the N-Panel under "Item"

[image: Mean Crease]

[image: With Crease]